# How to deploy only specify images within image stream?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Is it possible to create a deployment configuration to only deploy a container with certain criteria (e.g. a particular container label)?

The reason for this is I want to use one build config to build a certain group of images, but potentially deploy them in different ways (or sometimes not at all).

I imagine this would be a parameter in the image change trigger. e.g.

```
triggers:
  - type: "ImageChange"
    imageChangeParams:
      automatic: true 
      from:
        kind: "ImageStreamTag"
        name: "somecontainer:latest"
        namespace: "someproject"
      containerCriteria:
        - ???
```

If this is not possible, then how do I avoid duplication of build configs which are almost exactly the same?

Comment: From the perspective of a deployment configuration that is what the tag in image streams are for. So you currently have ``name: "somecontainer:latest"`` where ``latest`` is the tag. Adjust the tag to select a different version of an image from the image stream. You would still likely need a separate build configuration for generating each tagged version of the image in the image stream, unless building in a separate system and pushing them into OpenShift and setting up the image stream to reference them.

Comment: Would that not require a different build config (in order to tag the container differently)?

Comment: As I said, you would still need a separate build configuration so generated image is tagged differently. You can't generate more than one image out of a build configuration. The main point of what I am saying is that if you are only trying to select the image from an image stream, then you use the tag. It is unclear how this ``containersCriteria`` would work or how it is different.

Comment: Maybe I am confused about a few things. In my head imagestreams are collections of similar images, but it seems that actually they are versions of precisely one image.

Comment: It is up to you as to what interpretation you out on it. Usually it means versions of an image, but doesn't strictly have to be. Read https://blog.openshift.com/image-streams-faq/